# BCM - Database Tool 2013 on SQL 2008r2

Tags: microsoft-outlook, database, sql-server, business-contact-manager

Im trying to setup a Database with the Business Contact Manager Database Tool -2013 on one of our server. The tool is able to detect the SQL intance but can't create the Database.

I've gone through the following recommendations [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/troubleshoot-database-operations-in-business-contact-manager-HP010262612.aspx#_Toc255228781) trying to troubleshoot the issue but i've not been successful so far.

Server Info:

- Windows 2008R2 64bit.
- Sql Server 2008r2 64bit.
- BCM Database Tool 64bit.

Thanks

Comment: When it fails to create the DB, are you getting any specific error messages, or entries in the Event log?

Comment: It doesn't records any error in the event logs, the only information i found was that the Db get started and later on turn to SINGLE_USER access.

Comment: I think the following help sort out this issue.
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/business-contact-manager-and-office-2013-cannot/db70825e-6d6a-4993-8db4-79b25d70f366

Answer (score 1):

You are not following best practice for SQL. I am assuming it is also running on a domain?

Never run SQL service with Network service or local service. create a basic AD user or local user if no domnain (NOT ADMIN ACCOUNT) and run the SQL service as this user:

Please see below from technet:

User cannot create new database when SQL Server 2012 services logged on as Network Service
If a user of the BCM Database Tool is using SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2008 and is logged in as a Network Service, they may see the following error message:
Cannot create a new database. The operation has been rolled back. Please make sure the database service is running.
The workaround is to log on as a Local System instead of as a Network Service.

Comment: And you may also want to check your permissions on the directory the instance of SQL is mdf and ldf are saved in (data) and ensure that the user running the service has access to folders and write/modify permission as well.